# authentication error?

Tags: updates

I get this message:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcgmanager0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 33.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libcgmanager0
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

What can I do to fix this?

---

Edit 1:

When I do `sudo apt-key update`:

```
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key FBB75451: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key EFE21092: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg: unchanged: 4
```

---

Edit 2:

When I do `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Err us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Err us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Err security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err download.webmin.com sarge InRelease
Err security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err download.webmin.com sarge Release.gpg Could not resolve 'download.webmin.com'
Err webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk sarge InRelease

Err us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk sarge Release.gpg Could not resolve 'webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk'
Err us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done

W: Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch download.webmin.com/download/repository/dists/sarge/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository/dists/…

W: Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository/dists/… Could not resolve 'webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Can you please do: `sudo apt-key update` followed by `sudo apt-get update` - please let us know if you get any `BADSIG` or `NO_PUBKEY` errors.

Comment: Thanks, now try `sudo apt-get update` please.

Comment: Looks like DNS is failing for you. what happens if you type `ping us.archive.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: @CummingsAaron Next time just paste into your question as an edit - don't use comments... I added them as an edit.

Comment: @DavidPurdue I get "unknown host us.archive.ubuntu.com"

Comment: OK - DNS is not set up on your box, so it can't look up what it needs to validate the package. Fixing your DNS is beyond the scope of this question, so please get that fixed then try the `sudo apt-get update` again please.

Comment: @DavidPurdue how do I do that?

Comment: @DavidPurdue so I decided to change my network interfaces from being a Static IP Address Assignment to Dynamic IP Address Assignment (DHCP Client) that fixed the issue. I'm curious on where I went wrong? Because I followed:https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Comment: @CummingsAaron When you assigned the static IP address, you did not configure DNS - so apt-get has no idea how to translate the name `us.archive.ubuntu.com` into an IP address for the server. When you use DHCP, the DHCP client sets up DNS for you automatically based on information it received from the DHCP server.

Comment: I will write up an an answer based on these comments - please up vote and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `apt-get` operations are failing because DNS is not set up correctly on your Ubuntu box, hence `apt` can't communicate with the specified repositories.

Having your box set its address with DHCP will mean that its DHCP client will automatically set up DNS for you.

Alternately, please refer to this documentation for how to specify the DNS servers your box will use when configuring a static IP address: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-resolution